# How to listen to stream again when we come back to screen with back button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, qr-code, flutter-dependencies

I am listening to stream which scans QR Code. When the data is detected app navigates to another screen to show the data. But I am unable to figure out how to listen to stream again when I come back to scanning screen by pressing back button.

```
  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      this.controller = controller;
    });
    streamSubscription = controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async {
      result = scanData;

      if (result != null) {
        await goto();
      }

    });
  }

  void goto() async {
    await streamSubscription.pause();
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/history');
  }
```

Comment: you can call this function from the second page before navigator.pop();

Answer (score 0):

On the second page use `Navigator.of(context).pop(true)`

On your first page use

`bool back = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/history');`

back listen for the pop, then use

```
if (back) {
    call your stream listener()
}
```